# Redirect to an .aspx page that is in another project from a MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I have two projects in my solution. One is a `MVC 4` Project and the other one is a `Web Form` application. I have a `Report.aspx` page in the `Web Form` application. The question is: Can I redirect to `Report.aspx` from MVC project's actions or views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, should not be an issue. Do a

```
Responce.Redirect("[your url here]");
```

You can also use client side redirect using javascript (RegisterClientScript), with the following javascript command.

```
window.location.replace('your url');
```

Comment: I had a miss understanding. I thought that all the projects I have in my Solution will be published as one project and I can somehow redirect between them same as redirection between actions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Server.Transfer
It  still keeps the previous page in memory and can be accessed through the previous page property.

Server.Transfer("~/Default2.aspx");